# How can I Simplify This expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, binomial-coefficients

How can I simplify this expression?
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-i} {k+i \choose i}{n \choose k+i}p^{k+2i}$$
It looks like a version of newton's binomial where

$$(1+p)^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}p^k$$

but I am not sure how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-i} {k+i \choose i}{n \choose k+i}p^{k+2i}= \sum_{k=0}^{n-i} \frac{(k+i)!}{i! \cdot  k!} \frac{n!}{(k+i)! \cdot (n - (k+i))!}  p^{k+2i} =$$
$$\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}p^{2i}\sum_{k=0}^{n-i}\frac{(n-i)!}{k!(n-(k+i))!}p^k = {n \choose i} p^{2i} \sum_{k=0}^{n-i}{n - i \choose k}p^k =$$
$${n \choose i} p^{2i} (1+p)^{n-i}$$